# What aligned damage does a diabolic sorcerer cause?

Tags: spells, sorcerer, pathfinder-2e, alignment

Although the Demonic and Diabolic bloodlines in Pathfinder 2e grant access to the divine spell list, I don't see any character alignment requirements, as there are for a cleric.  If a diabolic sorcerer uses divine lance or some other spell that causes aligned damage, what alignment will that damage be?  Devils are lawful evil, but I see no reason the character couldn't be chaotic good, and that character might worship a god that has no relationship to their bloodline.

Comment: Are you interested specifically in Divine Lance or are you looking for an answer comprehensive to the Divine list for Sorcerers?

Comment: I was using Divine Lance as an example.  There are many spells on the Divine list that do aligned damage, and I expect they would all follow the same rules.

Comment: In what comments have you seen this information, and what do you mean by your third example?

Comment: @papidave Just as terminology: we're moderators not admins, and if you need us to do something, raise a flag (it's under the question next to share, edit, etc.). We aren't likely to catch every comment, especially not on a quiet question.

Comment: @papidave Stack Exchange truly has its own mess of a learning curve XD

Comment: @Akixkisu sorry - extra text was intended for clarification but just caused issues.  I removed it.  My third point was that sorcerers don't have to have a god - they could e.g. be atheists per page 440, but not if they want to cast spells with aligned damage.

Comment: @papidave no worries. I appreciate the follow-up :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use your Deity's alignment, not yours nor demon/devils'

Per the [answer to a related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/173829/28326) (and the fact that *angelic* bloodline provides the similar spell [*spiritual weapon*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=306) specifically), there is no problem with Divine Sorcerers casting such spells. Each such spell references "your deity", not the character's own alignment, so they will use whichever Deity their player selected.

---

It's always a good idea to talk with your GM about rules that contradict the narrative. They may adjust rules to fit what they feel makes sense (in this case, potentially limiting your *divine lance* to evil and lawful/chaotic and making your *spiritual weapon* appear Abyssal in origin) or else tying them to your personal alignment. Good GM's will also take into account how you perceive the narrative.

Comment: This is the correct-by-rules answer.  It's one that I would argue should be houseruled to be based on the origin of your sorcerous bloodline (because that's what would make *sense*, as it is the origin of your powers) but by the rules, this is correct.

Comment: Yeah I considered opening with "depends on the GM". Maybe I should throw in a p.s. to make sure to open with a conversation so players and GM's are on the same page regarding spell origin

Comment: @BenBarden Eh, I can definitely imagine magic metaphysics for this answer to make sense. For example, these spells are literally converting your beliefs into a weapon—so even though the divine energy to power the spell comes from an evil source, if you are good that evil source’s power is enjoying your good beliefs. It can make sense either way, it’s just a matter of deciding which way your game works.

Comment: @KRyan but it doesn't work that way if you somehow manage to be a good worshipper of an evil god?  If you're a CG worshipper of Arazni or a NG worshipper of Raumya with the Angelic bloodline, then it blasts as Evil?  I mean, you *can* justify anything, but....

Comment: Every rules question could be answered with "depends on the GM", so I think that's implied in any answer.  The problem with divine-casting sorcerers is that they don't need to have a deity at all to gain access to that spell list.

Comment: Having now read the related question, I see that Gods and Magic elaborated that these features require the character to have a feature.  I hope it's not necessarily a "real" deity, as I would like a diabolic goblin who mistakenly worships the imaginary chaotic deity "Lord SoupTable" to have access to the full spell list, based purely on his faith.

Comment: @papidave While you and I know that GM adjudication is a rule in itself (often "Rule 0"), it is often worth mentioning anyway. Particularly, I've noticed that Pathfinder 2e *expects* more GM adjudication than its direct predecessor, frequently saying so (just look at the [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/190980/28326) I just posted for an example). It's particularly useful for members who may be newer to the hobby, or have been used to GM's who were more hands-off on player character adjudications than necessary in Pathfinder/P2e.

Comment: In regards to your second comment, that's probably something that should be in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com)... but is not supported by *official* Golarion lore (hope you have fun with it at your own table(s) though!)

Comment: If we're saying that certain divine spells require your character to worship a deity, and that the alignment of that damage will match the alignment of that deity (which may be neither the alighment of the character, nor the bloodline ancestor), we should probably include that in the reply.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. I think the Header of my answer covers that pretty succinctly. "Use your Deity's alignment, not yours nor demon/devils'"

Comment: @BenBarden In that case, “what you believe in” is your god.

Comment: I had somehow overlooked the key text in each of the spells with aligned damage "You can't cast this spell if you don't have a deity..." -- an entirely redundant statement for clerics, but essential for divine-casting sorcerers.