# Are creatures with Stench auras affected by each others' Stench auras?

Tags: monsters, pathfinder-2e, aura

One of the Pathfinder 2E adventure paths features many [xulgaths](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=244), typically fighting in groups. Many xulgaths have some variant of a Stench aura. For example, the level 1 [Xulgath Warrior](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=418) has:

> Stench ([aura](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=206), [olfactory](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=246)) 30 feet. A creature that enters the area must attempt a DC 16 Fortitude save. On a failure, the creature is sickened 1, and on a critical failure, the creature also takes a –5-foot status penalty to its Speeds for 1 round. While within the aura, the creature takes a –2 circumstance penalty to saves to recover from the sickened condition. A creature that succeeds at its save is temporarily immune to all xulgaths’ stenches for 1 minute.

The wording of the aura trait implies that a creature is unaffected by its own stench aura.

> An aura is an emanation that continually ebbs out from you, affecting creatures within a certain radius.

But xulgath stat blocks don't specify that they are immune to olfactory effects in general. What happens when multiple xulgaths (or other creatures with Stench auras) are within each others' auras? Do they all need to make Fortitude saves versus the effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Probably not

It is specifically up to GM adjudication, but this probably falls under this line in [Auras](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=5)

> The GM might determine that a monster’s aura doesn’t affect its own allies. For example, a creature might be immune to a monster’s frightful presence if they have been around each other for a long time.